# SQL Inner join and count

Tags: sql

Setup as below works.
But, what I want to achive is to count how many rows there is in `BlogComment` where `BlogComment.BlogPostId = BlogPost.BlogPostId`.

Anyone got suggestion ?

```
SELECT * FROM BlogPost
INNER JOIN BlogUser
ON BlogPost.BlogUserId = BlogUser.BlogUserId
INNER JOIN Category
ON BlogPost.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId
INNER JOIN BlogComment
ON BlogPost.BlogPostId = BlogComment.BlogPostId
Order By BlogPost.BlogPostId Desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the data plus a count (as opposed to just the count) you can create an inline query in the from clause to do this.

```
SELECT *, 
       COALESCE(c.count_post_id,0) as count_post_id
FROM   blogpost 
       INNER JOIN bloguser 
         ON blogpost.bloguserid = bloguser.bloguserid 
       INNER JOIN category 
         ON blogpost.categoryid = category.categoryid 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT blogpostid, 
                          COUNT(blogpostid) count_post_id
                   FROM   blogcomment
                   GROUP BY blogpostid) c
         ON c.blogpostid = blogpost.blogpostid 
ORDER  BY blogpost.blogpostid DESC
```

Some RDMS give additional options like using CTEs or Cross Apply

Comment: Think this is more what i need.
But i get error:
Column 'BlogComment.BlogPostId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
The multi-part identifier "countcomments.commentcount" could not be bound.

Comment: @miker doh. Forgot the group by clause in the inline query I fixed it

Comment: Conrad. Thanks.. But get this when I run it.
The multi-part identifier "countcomments.commentcount" could not be bound.

Comment: @miker I made the sin of using names that were too similar. I had reversed the table and field aliases. I've updated my answer to use aliases that even I couldn't mess-up :)

Comment: In BlogPost table, Ive got 1 row and when I run your answer, it returns 2 rows with same data

Comment: I'm guess you have two records in the blogComment table? Do you want the comments **and** the count of comments or just the count? If you just want the count remove the `INNER JOIN blogcomment ON blogpost.blogpostid = blogcomment.blogpostid`

Comment: As it is now, I only return rows if blogpost.blogpostid is matched in blogcomment.blogpostid. If I want to return all data from blogpost aswell regardless if blogpost.blogpostid is on blogcomment table or not.

Comment: @Miker I updated the answer. You need to convert it to a `LEFT JOIN` to the inline query and add a `COALESCE` on the count

Answer (score 1):

Is it how many comments each blogpost have you want?
then it should be

```
SELECT blogpostid, 
       COUNT(*) as TotalComments 
FROM   blogpost p 
       JOIN blogcomment c 
         ON p.blogpostid = c.blogpostid 
GROUP  BY blogpostid;
```

Comment: Yes, thats correct Mikael. How do I add your line to my sp?
And aslo adding AS TotalComments

Comment: @miker what do you mean by sp? I changed the query to name the count as totalcomments. If you also want the total number of comments (over all blogposts) you add "with rollup" at the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   blogpost a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   blogcomment 
               WHERE  blogcomment.blogpostid = a.blogpostid)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
SELECT BlogPost.*, BlogUser.*, Category.*, BlogComment.*, COUNT(BlogComment.BlogCommentId) FROM BlogPost
INNER JOIN BlogUser
ON BlogPost.BlogUserId = BlogUser.BlogUserId
INNER JOIN Category
ON BlogPost.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId
INNER JOIN BlogComment
ON BlogPost.BlogPostId = BlogComment.BlogPostId
GROUP BY BlogPost.BlogPostId Order By BlogPost.BlogPostId Desc
```

Comment: I edited my post - try again - the `BlogCommentId` from the `COUNT` clause is the primary key from table `BlogComment` - change it with its actual name if that differs

Comment: All right. Ill try it.
I think i made my self unclear in my question.
I only want to count rows from BlogComment where BlogComment.BlogPostId matches BlogPost.BlogPostId